# JDBC getUpdateCount is returning 0, but 1 row is updated, in SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc, jooq

Anyone ever seen this?  I'm using MS SQL Server 2008, and I've tried it with two different JDBC drivers (jtds, and Microsoft's). I run a simple statement to update a row, and it does update it, but `getUpdateCount` returns 0. If I try it for different tables, it returns 1 as expected.  It's something about this one table.

```
PreparedStatement ps = 
  conn.prepareStatement("select count(*) from foo_users where user_id = 1")
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
rs.next()
println(" count(*) is " + rs.getInt(1));    // Prints 1

ps = conn.prepareStatement("update foo_users set is_admin = 1 where user_id = 1")
ps.execute()
int count = ps.getUpdateCount()
println(" update count is " + count)        // Prints 0.  WTF.
```

What is causing this?

*Update in response to comment:* Yes, `executeUpdate` works.  But I ask this question because I'm using a query library called [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) which is returning incorrect results because it's calling `execute` and `getUpdateCount`.  I left this out of my question originally, because I don't think it is the library's fault.

Comment: Any reason you're not just using `int count = executeUpdate();` to start with, instead of calling `execute()`?

Comment: Yes. I'm actually using another library (jOOQ) which is calling `execute()`.  Maybe I should post on their mailing list too.  As you suggest, `executeUpdate` works fine.

Comment: Have you actually checked the value returned by `execute()`? Only if it is `false` will `getUpdateCount()` return an update count. Otherwise you first need to call `getMoreResults()` (maybe multiple times). Now I would expect an update count for this specific statement. And if `execute` returned `true`, `getUpdateCount()` should have returned `-1`, but you never know.

Comment: Yes, `execute()` does return false.

Comment: Do any triggers fire when you run this update? E.g. triggers that might [raise an error](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/Rzj96HIliBo)?

Comment: Just checked. We have no triggers in our database.

Comment: Hard to say what the issue is. Do you have a reproducible test case?

Comment: if the connection has SET NOCOUNT ON, SQL server will not return the rows affected by a statement

Answer (score 0):

You need "executeUpdate" for your update statement.

executeUpdate returns the rowcount. "execute" just returns false if there is no recordset returned, which there wouldn't be for an UPDATE.

Comment: Did you read my entire question? I explain the specific reason that I'm not asking about `executeUpdate`.  `execute` and `getUpdateCount` should work, according to Java docs.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late answer but this works in sql server 2022 with the latest ms jdbc drivers 12.2:

```sql
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select count(*) from foo_users where user_id = 1");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
rs.next();
System.out.println(" count(*) is " + rs.getInt(1));    // Prints 1

ps = conn.prepareStatement("update foo_users set is_admin = 1 where user_id = 1");
ps.execute();
int count = ps.getUpdateCount();
System.out.println(" update count is " + count);        // Prints 1.
```